# Allow to run a string as the corresponding vim commands in elisp

Tags: spacemacs, evil-mode

This list of `call-interactively` actually represents a very simple Vim macro: `vk=o`

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "SPC dg")
  (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    (call-interactively 'evil-visual-char)
    (call-interactively 'evil-previous-line)
    (call-interactively 'indent-region)
    (call-interactively 'evil-open-below)))
```

**Question**
Is there a simple way to execute vim commands inside elisp?

**Notes**
I have found that you can bind vim macros to keyboard shortcuts using `global-set-key`.
Something like this: `(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-l") "vk=o")`
But trying to see how global-set-key was doing it, it lead me to compiled C code from `define-key` which didn't help much.

I am looking to write something perhaps alike:

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "SPC dg")
  (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    ;; some code
    (eval-vim-macro "vk=o")))
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try defining the binding to be a string instead of a lambda: 
`(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "Q") "jjjo")`.

Comment: I can already accomplish this (though I used `global-set-key`) and bind and specific key combination to a given string representing vim commands.
What I'm looking for is a way to bind to something I can reuse in a function definition so I can use some of my currently defined kbd macros directly inside my elisp code!

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: I ended up using `evil-ex-execute`.

Stumbled upon this question looking for the same thing. Hope my findings help future travelers.

What I did to find this out was:

- `C-h k :`, which directed me towards the `evil-ex` in `evil-ex.el` file.
- Casually browsed `evil-ex.el` file to find out the function that seemed to make sense.
- Tried out the `evil-ex-execute` to find that this is exactly what I need.

Singing praises to Emacs introspection capabilities!